# C# Development with Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I have a webservice.asmx file with a webservice.asmx.cs

If I make changes to the file... How do I reset Mono, so that it will pick up these changes?

I have tried an apache restart - but this only restarts apache, not the mono engine.

It seems mono scans and caches everything on start...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"sudo killall mono" to brute-force restart all mono processes.

Comment: That will also kill other Mono websites hosted on the machine, if any.

Answer (score 3):

You can restart mod-mono using the Control Panel. See [this](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono#Control_panel)